# How to change test case arguments for TestCaseData Nunit

Tags: c#, nunit

Using c#, Nunit 3.

I have test case source, which many of my tests share.
Something like:

```
public static IEnumerable TestCaseSourceMethod()
{
    foreach (String str in someMethodHere)
    {
        //do some stuff
        yield return new TestCaseData(newString).SetCategory(testCategory);
    }
}
```

And I use it in Tests like

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("TestCaseSourceMethod")]
...
```

Now I have new test method, that should use the same data from TestCaseSourceMethod but needs additional test argument.

I came up with something like:

```
foreach (TestCaseData tcd in TestCaseSourceMethod())
{
    //how to change tcd to include new test case argument, or create new test case data based on tcd
    yield return newtcd;
}
```

I am able to do `tcd.Returns("aaa");` in order to change the expected returned value, or `tcd.SetCategory("aaaaa");`, but I wasn't able to find a way to change the test case arguments themselves.

Comment: Create a new Test case source method that draws data from the same place the original one does and make your modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always move common logic in own method and re-use it.
Create method which *do some stuff* and return parameter for the tests

```
public static string DoSomeStaff(string someValue)
{
    // do some stuff
    return newString;
}
```

Then

```
public static IEnumerable TestCaseSourceMethod()
{
    foreach (String str in someMethodHere)
    {
        var newString = DoSomeStaff(str);
        yield return new TestCaseData(newString).SetCategory(testCategory);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable SpecialTestCaseSourceMethod()
{
    foreach (String str in someMethodHere)
    {
        var newString = DoSomeStaff(str);
        var otherArgument = GetOtherArgument();
        yield return new TestCaseData(newString, otherArgument).SetCategory(testCategory);
    }
}
```

Another approach - create extension method, which return new `TestCaseData` with extra arguments. Returning new instance of `TestCaseData` is important in case when tests executed in parallel.

```
public static TestCaseData AddArguments(this TestCaseData source, params object[] args)
{
    var arguments = source.Arguments.Concat(args).ToArray();
    return new TestCaseData(arguments);
}
```

And use it in method which generate special cases

```
public static IEnumerable SpecialTestCaseSourceMethod()
{
    foreach (var testcase in TestCaseSourceMethod())
    {
        yield return testcase.AddArguments(otherArgument, extraArgument);
    }
}
```

You can copy category from original test case inside `AddArguments` methods.
As mentioned before, it is good to have different instances of test case data, because of possible problems when tests executed in parallel.
Name of method `AddArguments`

```
public static TestCaseData AddArguments(this TestCaseData source, params object[] args)
{
    var arguments = source.Arguments.Concat(args).ToArray();
    var category = source.Properties.Get(PropertyNames.Category).ToString();
    return new TestCaseData(arguments).SetCategory(category);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I would use that eventually. But as I am able to do tcd..Returns("aaa"), I see no reason not to be able to do tcd.AddOneMoreArg("new"). And if this is possible, I'd rather use this option.

Comment: @Jeni, you can always create your own extension method - check updated answer

Comment: OK! This looks almost 100% what I am looking for. My only problem is this way I would lose the other properties of the original TestCaseData. In my example code above this would be the Category. Is there a way to do this transparently copying all else from source, or I should do it explicitly one by one for category, expected result, etc.

Comment: @Jeni, you can copy category in the same extension method, check updated answer